# Como acionar um método quando o usuário apertar a tecla delete ou return (apagar)?

Tags: angularjs, teclado

No meu form tenho um campo cliente. Preciso que, quando o usuário apertar a tecla delete ou return (apagar), seja acionado um método que tenho na minha controller, como posso capturar se foi acionado uma dessas teclas?

estou usando AngularJs

esse é o meu input:

```
<input placeholder="Digite as iniciais para fazer a pesquisa." class="md-input label-fixed" ng-model="registro2.razao"/>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38220874/detect-if-key-delete-was-pressed-with-angularjs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá tenta adicionar a directiva ao teu input:

```
ng-keydown="teclaPress($evento)"
```

e no teu controlador adiciona a função **teclaPress**

```
  $scope.teclaPress = function(ObjKey) {
    // teu codigo por exemplo debug
    console.log(ObjKey.key); // Tecla que clicaste
  }
```